# available stock sql query in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a two table stock in and stock out.

in stock in. range=stock and color is different color id

STOCK IN return

```
sum(rang) color
       17 1
       15 2
        7 4
```

& in stock out return

```
sum(rang) color
        3 4
```

and i want out put like this but is not coming i try everything

```
total stock | Sold Stock | Av Stock | color Id
         17 |       0    |       17 | 1
         15 |       0    |       15 | 2
          7 |       3    |        4 | 4
```

Plese Help Thanks in adv.

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data *in the question*.  Stack Overflow questions should not depend on external sites for their content.  Plus, your question doesn't even have the links.

Comment: oh edited. check. & please tell me.

Comment: In the time it took you to post the picture and copy-paste the link, you could have just written out the data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select IN.sum(rang) as TotalStock,
    (IN.sum(rang) - OUT.sum(rang)) as AvStock ,
    IN.color as Color
    from stockIn IN , stockOut OUT
    where IN.color = OUT.color ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 Select sum(si.rang) as TotalStock,sum(ifnull(so.ostock,0)) as OutStock,
  sum(si.rang-ifnull(so.ostock,0) ) as avgstock,si.color from stockin si 
 left join 
  (select sum(rang) as ostock,color from stockout group by color) so on si.color=so.color
  group by si.color
```

Comment: it's show wrong  totalstock,  if  there  is multiple  entry in stockout table using same colorId it  shows  wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT 
    sin.rang, 
    IFNULL(sum(sout.rang), 0) as sold, 
    sin.rang - IFNULL(sum(sout.rang), 0) AS av_stock, 
    sin.color 
FROM stock_in sin 
LEFT JOIN stock_out sout ON sout.color = sin.color
GROUP BY sin.color;
```

checkout the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/743ac/6)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem,

```
select  stIn.rang as total,
    isnull(stout.rang,0) as Sold, 
    stIn.rang - isnull(stOut.rang,0) as Av,
    stin.color as Id
from stockIn stIn left outer join stockOut stOut on stIn.color = stOut.color
```

Comment: You can also use `coalesce` in stead of  `isnull`.